# Conjugate fields of algebraic element

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K= \Bbb{Q}(\theta)$ be an algebraic number field of degree $n$ and let $\theta_1=\theta,\ldots,\theta_n$  be the conjugates of $\theta$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. Suppose that there are exactly $m$ distinct fields among $\Bbb{Q}(\theta_1),\ldots,\Bbb{Q}(\theta_n)$. Prove that $m$ divides $n$ and each field occurs $n/m$ times.

Comment: Since there is a natural group action and you're asking about divisibility, a good place to start is the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Comment: Take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) as well as [the MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619) for typesetting formulas. Think about Token Toucan's hint. Editing in whatever you got would be a nice way of adding context. If that is too difficult, may be you can do a simple example such as $\theta=\root4\of2$.

Comment: I feell that @TokenToucan's hint makes the problem harder. Suppose that $d_i$ of the fields are isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}(\theta_i)$. By symmetry (the conjugates of $\theta_i$ are the conjugates of $\theta = \theta_1$), the number $d = d_i$ doesn't depend on $i$, so the $n$ fields $\mathbf{Q}(\theta_i)$ are partitioned into $m$ blocks of $d$ fields, so $md=n$.

Comment: @user760870 I am pretty sure your argument is in the same in spirit as mine by orbit-stabilizer but it just unravels things in terms of this problem to avoid actually mentioning that theorem. I don’t think one way is easier than the other.

Comment: @TokenToucan The most natural orbit-stabilizer argument I see requires two applications of the orbit-stabilizer theorem together with Lagrange's theorem; that certainly seems more complicated to me.

Comment: @user760870 unfortunately I think you then have the wrong argument in mind, which perhapsexplains why you thought it was harder. You do not need to use orbit-stabilizer twice, or Lagrange. Like I said, if you take your argument and write it in terms of group actions you will get the same thing I had in mind.

Comment: @TokenToucan: perhaps you could indulge me? If $G$ acts on the roots and $N$ is the subgroup which sends $\mathbf{Q}(\theta_1)$ to an isomorphic field, then $d = |G/N|$ which you then have to show divides $n$. If you note that this quantity doesn't depend on the choice of root, you deduce that $n$ has a partition into sets of size $d$, but then the actual "Orbit-Stabilizer" part of the argument doesn't actually play any role. I *guess* you could argue that for another root $\theta_i = g_i \theta$ that the orbit has size $d_i = |G/N_i| = |G/g_i Ng^{-1}_i|=|G/N| = d$, but this seems to ...

Comment: be forcing the Orbit-Stabilizer into the argument where it's not really necessary. Alternatively, if $H$ is the stabilizer of $\theta$, then $H \subset N$ and so $|G/N||N/H| = |G/H|$. Now $d=|H/N|$ is integral ("Lagrange") and $|G/H| = n$ by the Orbit-Stabilizer again, so $md=n$ (this was my first guess as to your argument). This second argument at least uses Orbit-Stabilizer in some genuine way, but you seemed to say it was not your argument. If your argument was the first one then we can agree to disagree whether one is easier, but perhaps you had a third way.

Comment: Sure: let $G$ act on the conjugate fields. The action is transitive, so by O-S, the number of conjugates is the index in $G$ of the stabilizer of $K(\theta)$. The stabilizer must contain the subgroup $H$, so the index of the stabilizer in $G$ divides the index of $H$, which is $n$.

Comment: The last step is multiplicativity of index, *not* lagrange. Indices are *always* integers since by definition they are the # of cosets which has to be an integer (either way Lagrange is so elementary that I don't think that it would detract from the argument if I had used it). It appears the ingredient you are missing is the transitivity of the action which is equivalent to your "by symmetry" remark.

Comment: @TokenToucan you seem confused because the fact that the index is an integer is *exactly* Lagrange's theorem. So you use OS twice ($[G:H] = n$ and $[G:N] = m$) and then use Lagrange, exactly as I suggest. It's a perfectly correct argument, and not particularly difficult, but certainly unnecessary since you don't even need to know the definition of a *group* for my answer. There is nothing missing from my answer; the fact that the fields $\mathbf{Q}(\theta_i)$ are isomorphic is immediate (by definition) since they are all $\mathbf{Q}[x]/P(x)$ where $P(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\theta$.

Comment: No, I don’t use O-S twice. Index $n$ is Galois theory. I am afraid we just disagree about definitions or something.

Comment: Galois theory is even harder than everything else used here!  Not to mention that the result in Galois theory you are implicitly using is proved precisely using the OS theorem in this exact setting (To show $|G|| \le [L:E]$ with $G = \mathrm{Aut}(L/E)$ and equality for Galois extensions, a key step is choosing $\theta \in L \setminus E$, $H = \mathrm{Aut}(L/E(\theta))$, and then using OS to deduce $|G|=|H||\Sigma|$, where $\Sigma$ is the orbit of $\theta$ (so $|\Sigma| = [E(\theta):E]$ when $G$ is transitive and the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ is separable).

Comment: So while both are perfectly acceptable arguments in a Galois theory course, I think it's hard to argue that a proof using Galois Theory + OS + the index of a subgroup is an integer (Lagrange) counts as harder than a proof not requiring the definition of a group.  Anyway, none of this is meant with any animus and your argument is a perfectly reasonable one.